# Xamarin Forms - Show / Hide Frame based off Picker

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms, picker

I have a picker that has two values.

1. Click and Collect
2. Shipping

How would I display the correct frame according to what was selected in the picker?

For example if user selects "Click and Collect" it will display the "frameClickandCollect". If the user select "Shipping" it will display the "frameShipping".

Here's my XAML code:

```
<Frame x:Name="frameDeliveryOptions" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False">
   
    <StackLayout>
      
      <Label Text="Delivery Options:" FontSize="18" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
         
      <Picker x:Name="DeliveryOptionPicker" Title="Select a delivery option" TitleColor="Black">
            
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
               
               <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
               <x:String>Click and Collect</x:String>
               <x:String>Shipping</x:String>
               </x:Array>

            </Picker.ItemsSource>
      
       </Picker>
    
     </StackLayout>

</Frame>

<Frame x:Name="frameClickandCollect" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False">
   
    <StackLayout>
      
      <Label Text="Click and Collect Yo" FontSize="18" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      
    </StackLayout>

</Frame>

<Frame x:Name="frameShipping" BorderColor="LightGray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False">
   
    <StackLayout>
      
      <Label Text="Shipping Yo" FontSize="18" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      
    </StackLayout>

</Frame>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use picker SelectedIndexChanged event to hide/show your frame by using IsVisible= "false"/"true"
**XAML:**

```
<Picker x:Name="DeliveryOptionPicker" Title="Select a delivery option" TitleColor="Black" SelectedIndexChanged="DeliveryOptionPicker_SelectedIndexChanged">

                <Picker.ItemsSource>

                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Click and Collect</x:String>
                        <x:String>Shipping</x:String>
                    </x:Array>

                </Picker.ItemsSource>

            </Picker>
```

**c# :**

```
private void DeliveryOptionPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        //you can also use SelectedItem

        if (DeliveryOptionPicker.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            frameClickandCollect.IsVisible = false;
        }

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! thanks @ijigarsolanki keep up the great work mate.